# i rendred both the login and registration controllers in a single twig page but it kept on giving me error

Tags: php, symfony

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="login-signup-form">
        {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="login-signup-form">
        {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct() must
>   implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface, none
>   given, called in C:\wamp64\www\test\var\cache\dev\classes.php on line
>   3906 and defined").

Comment: what are versions of FOSUserBundle and Symfony? did you looked at this: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2744

Comment: thx man it worked like charm

Comment: Could you please write some words about it as an answer, I will be happy to upvote

Answer (score 2):

the problem was all in the FOS version as it reads things differently i changed it in the composer.json from  "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev" to "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.1" and did the update on the composer works like a charm